# The import com.fasterxml.jackson cannot be resolved error on trying to setup a legacy Java Spring boot application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, jackson

Following import in an existing class is throwing a compilation error "import cannot be resolved" on eclipse -

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
```

The corresponding jar inclusion in pom.xml is -

```
<properties>
    <fasterxml.version>0.7.0</fasterxml.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>${fasterxml.version} </version>
</dependency>
```

I checked that the corresponding jar file is not present in .m2.
There is no such directory as jackson-module-hibernate inside .m2/fasterxml/

However, jar corresponding to another declaration is present in .m2 -

com.fasterxml.jackson.core
                jackson-annotations
                2.6.1

Is present in .m2/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.1 
as jackson-annotations-2.6.1.jar

**Setup details**

Maven version - 3.3

Java version - 1.8.

Eclipse latest version - 2019-06.

I could not verify the absence of the first jar in the working sandbox setup, but that's how it should be, as we had taken a backup of the .m2 directory. How is it possible that the application runs in another setup without the presence of the jar.

Note - I am still a struggler when it comes to maven dependencies and the setup of this legacy project has made me pull hairs. I am trying to do the setup on eclipse. It got setup sometime back, after a lot of struggle, but before I could document all the steps/workarounds we made, I deleted the working setup by mistake.

**Update**

The pom declaration for jackson-annotations is in the pom of another project. That project has been included in the pom of the dependent project as -

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.dependencies</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-project</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need:

- Execute `mvn clean compile` from Command Line, on another project
- Execute `mvn clean compile` on your project
- Right-click on Project > *Maven* > *Update project...*

Comment: Note version change. Your required dependency is part of the fetched jar file for the above declaration

Comment: I think I did some mistake in understangin. I have this declaration that you have mentioned. I also have the jar jackson-annotations-2.6.1.jar as already mentioned inside .m2/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.1. However, I am still getting the compilation error. This declaration is in the pom of another project. That project has been included in the pom of the dependent project. See update in question.

Comment: I am having a doubt whether the dependencies defined in pom of the dependency project are loaded at all. I cannot see any `Maven Dependencies` folder under that project in file tree structure. I can only see the pom.xml.

Comment: Please try `Right-click on project` > `Maven` > `Update project`

Comment: if it not helps - go to your project root(that which contains problem) and run `mvn clean compile`

Comment: That `<dependencyManagement>` section means that  your project inherits all of the dependencies from the project specified in this `<dependencyManagement>` section

Comment: So, with regard to your description, you don't need additional entry, but rather just to try compile your project

Comment: Seems like an issue where Eclipse just do not sees your dependencies just they are not fetched

Comment: So if above suggestion won't help - run `mvn clean compile` on another project also

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Comment: No, still the same import cannot be resolved issue. I ran the clean compile and also downgraded the maven version to 3.3 from 3.6 so that it is same as working environment.

Comment: How the `mvn clean compile` went? Errors, warnings?